# Object.defineProperties/create really needed?

Tags: javascript, oop

Some projects use `Object.create()` or `Object.defineProperties()` function. I wonder is is recommended? Whats the difference between

```
x = Object.create(null);
```

vs

```
x = {}
```

And

```
x = {}
x.__proto__.hello = function() { 
    console.log("hello"); 
}
```

vs

```
x = Object.create(null);
Object.defineProperty(x, "hello", { 
    value: function() { 
        console.log("hello"); 
    } 
});
```

`defineProperty/create` seems very verbose and long to me. When/Why do I use them? Perhaps the good might be to enforce getters/setters/overriding properties?

Comment: @AndyRay, I saw that b4, except I didnt really see much point in using it (apart from more "private" properties) ... so I hopped posting a qn will clear things up more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a huge difference. Have a look at the docs!

- [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) does create an Object that inherits from the first argument, `null` in your case. In contrast, `{}` - or `new Object()` -  creates a new object that inherits from `Object.prototype`.
- [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is non-standard and should not be used. However, in your case you just do `Object.prototype.hello = function() {…};`. Never extend that object with enumerable properties, never ever!
- [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) does define a property on an object with a special descriptor object. The `enumerable`, `configurable` and `writable` attributes default to `false`, which means that you wont be able to `delete x.hello` for example, or assign any other value.

Your first snippet creates a plain object, which inherits a `hello` method from `Object.prototype`, while your second snippet creates an object inheriting from nothing and having a non-editable `hello` property. I don't see much relatedness.

Comment: Hmm is http://jsfiddle.net/vHx6s/ the recommended way to do classes? If so whats the diff between line 2 (`this.name = name`) and 3 (`Object.defineProperty(this, "name2", {...})`)? Which is recommended? Can I say I only use `Object.defineProperty` when I want to restrict things like not writable, configurable/overwritable etc?

Comment: Yes, you will. Yet I can't see a reason to set `enumberable` and `configurable` of `name2` to `false` - so why would you use it? It's your decision whether the usage of `defineProperty` is reasonable.

Comment: I think we are thinking the same way, seems like `defineProperty` is just a longer way of acheiving the same thing ... personally about private/public properties, I think its not really worth it to sacrifice more readable and understandable code :)